# How can I print output of a class method to console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, class, oop

I have a subclass called `check_price` which inherits from Constraint. I want to check the list `unitPrices`. What's the simplest way to print the list `unitPrices`  to console so I can check it?

```
class check_price(Constraint):

    def __init__(self, column):
        self._column = column

    def is_valid(self, table_data):
        column_data = table_data[self._column_name]
    
        group = table_data.groupby('StockCode')
        unitPrices = group.apply(lambda x: x['UnitPrice'].unique())
 
        print(unitPrices)

        bulk = column_data >= 50
        if bulk:
            valid_price = column_data == min(unitPrices)
    
        return bulk & valid_price

#test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Quantity': [100, 30, 40, 30,60],
'UnitPrice': [2.50, 5, 2, 3.99, 2.99],
'StockCode':['72083Z', '72083Z', '84006B', '22423S', '22423S']})  

print(df)
```

Comment: `print(unitPrices)`?  Can you clarify 1) how you're running the program 2) what invokes the printing (e.g. you want a method, you want it to print automatically as it's called etc)

Comment: you call print on it? if this class of your does not print in a useful way, you define a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__str__) special method

Comment: @anon01 1) I call some other classes to load the data `check_price` is called last to check the data 2) I guess I would like it as its called,I would like to see what `unitPrices` looks like. With functions I'm used to printing the objects I need to do this.

Comment: in that case you can put your print in the `__init__`

Comment: @Copperfield From my understanding `unitPrices` is produced after initialisation within the `is_valid` function so I get an error when trying to print `unitPrice` in __init__. `__str__` gives no error but also no output.  Could you suggest any other methods of retrieving list `unit prices`?

Comment: `unitPrices` is a local variable to `is_valid`. It *only exists* when `is_valid` is executing. So if you want to print it, you have to `print(unitPrices)` somewhere in there. Which seems to be what you are doing? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the code you posted, you already do `print(unitPrices)` in the method is_valid, which will be executed whenever this one is called, so assuming you also want to print this unitPrices at any other time, then you need to save its value withing this class so it be accessible at any time, for example you can do this

```
class check_price(Constraint):

    def __init__(self, column):
        self._column = column
        self.unitPrices = None #we initialize it to None because its value is calculate elsewhere

    def is_valid(self, table_data):
        column_data = table_data[self._column_name]
    
        group = table_data.groupby('StockCode')
        unitPrices = group.apply(lambda x: x['UnitPrice'].unique())
        
        self.unitPrices = unitPrices # we save the calculate value
        
        print(unitPrices)

        bulk = column_data >= 50
        if bulk:
            valid_price = column_data == min(unitPrices)
    
        return bulk & valid_price
```

and can be used like this

```
#do your stuff
my_check = check_price(some_data)
#do some other stuff
print(my_check.unitPrices)
```

like this `print(my_check.unitPrices)` will print None if the `is_valid` haven't be called yet but if it was then will print whatever value it have from the last time `is_valid` was called